# Proj4 Task not working - Northing Easting to Lat Lng

Tags: coordinate-system, proj

I usually post in StackOverFlow - if this is the incorrect area to post - I apologise.

I have trying to convert a lot of northings / eastings to lat lng

I have code below working:
In ruby using this gem https://github.com/dark-panda/ffi-proj4

```
 class PostCodeNode < Node
  require 'ffi-proj4'
   attr_accessor :postcode, :sector, :district

  def self.from_northerns_and_eastings(northing, easting, postcode)
     srcPoint = Proj4::Point.new(easting, northing)
     srcProj = Proj4::Projection.new('+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs')
     dstProj = Proj4::Projection.new('+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs')
     dstPoint = srcProj.transform(dstProj, easting, northing, 0)
     lat, lon = to_degrees(dstPoint.x), to_degrees(dstPoint.y)
     new lat, lon, postcode
  end

   def initialize(lat, lon, postcode)
     @postcode = postcode.gsub(/\s+/, '')
     @sector   = if @postcode.length == 7 then @postcode[0..4] else @postcode[0..3] end
     @district = @postcode[0..2]
     super(lat, lon)
   end
  end
end
```

However, the lat / lon that I am out putting end up in the middle of the sea! So I know I am doing something very wrong!

```
     dstPoint = srcProj.transform(dstProj, easting, northing, 0)
```

This line in particular is where the "magic" happens! In the test library on the git repo the test specifies some unknown numbers to me, I am not sure if I have my input data correct!
https://github.com/dark-panda/ffi-proj4/blob/master/test/transformation_tests.rb

```
def setup
    @proj_wgs84 = Proj4::Projection.new(["init=epsg:4326"])
    @proj_gk    = Proj4::Projection.new(["init=epsg:31467"])
    @proj_merc  = Proj4::Projection.new(["proj=merc"])
    @lon =  8.4293092923
    @lat = 48.9896114523
    @rw = 3458305
    @hw = 5428192
    @zw = -5.1790915237
  end

  def test_gk_to_wgs84
    to = @proj_gk.transform(@proj_wgs84, @rw, @hw, @zw)

    assert_in_delta @lon, to.x * Proj4::RAD_TO_DEG, TOLERANCE
    assert_in_delta @lat, to.y * Proj4::RAD_TO_DEG, TOLERANCE
    assert_in_delta 0, to.z, TOLERANCE
  end

  def test_wgs84_to_gk
    point = @proj_wgs84.transform(
      @proj_gk,
      @lon * Proj4::DEG_TO_RAD,
      @lat * Proj4::DEG_TO_RAD,
      0
    )
    assert_equal @rw, point.x.round
    assert_equal @hw, point.y.round
    assert_in_delta @zw, point.z, TOLERANCE
  end
```

There is no documentation with this ruby gem so I am doing a little bit of guess work, but I think I am nearly there.

Can someone see my error, so I can return the right lon/lat.

I am writing this in Jruby so any better Java Libraries could also be used :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I used Jcoord to do this..

For anyone interested in how to do this in Jruby I did it like this:

```
  require 'java'
  require 'jcoord-1.1-b.jar'
  java_import "uk.me.jstott.jcoord.CoordinateSystem"
  java_import "uk.me.jstott.jcoord.LatLng"
  java_import "uk.me.jstott.jcoord.OSRef"
  latlng = OSRef.new(easting.to_f,northing.to_f).toLatLng
  lat, lon = latlng.lat, latlng.lng
```

Thanks